# Updating a tile from a background task

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm using C# and Windows Phone 8.1 as Universal App.

In Microsoft samples for windows phone 8.1 you can find a sample with 'Updating a tile from a background task' name and it is for C# and C++.

I can't use C++ because I do not know it and Microsoft sample for this work its to hard for me. How can I learn to update a Tile from Background?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where to start because your question is quite broad. If you know [how to create and update a tile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868260.aspx), then you can also read about how to update live tiles for instance, [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj991805.aspx)